# Android Dog Repellent proved to work

Tags: android, audio

I walk a lot on lonely roads, and often encounter dogs, that sometimes try to bite me. Usually I just drive them away with a stick, but I remember the Dog Repellent used by some joggers was more efficient and convenient.

Is there a Dog Repellent app for Android?

References please. There are a few apps for this on Play Store, but I want apps that have been proved to work (tested in real life).

I guess it depends on hardware, so solutions should mention the hardware on which they were tested.